# Does Google V8 work in similar way to Java Virtual Machine?

Tags: java, javascript, node.js, v8

I know that V8 is a JavaScript engine, but does it work in a similar way to a Java Virtual Machine?

If it doesn’t work in the same manner, what are the differences? Does V8 compile JavaScript to machine language directly?

Comment: No one really answered you. The answer is yes: they both are virtual machines, one for java the other to javascript (which are very differente languages). In the case of the jvm, this vm translates in runtime (i.e. intreprets it or JIT - just in time compilation) from java bytecode into your cpu's machine code. In the case of V8, it intreperts javascript directly into machine code. The ways they do this translations may have differences but the overall ideia is the same.

Comment: Thanks @AndréRosa! And why not add it as a proper answer down below?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Excepting that Lars Bak was instrumental to both projects, they are unrelated.

[V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/) is a JavaScript engine that compiles JavaScript to native machine code, used most notably by Google Chrome and Node js.

The [JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine) is a virtual machine that runs bytecode produced by a Java compiler.

One is a **JavaScript** engine, and the other is a **Java** Virtual Machine, and note that Java and JavaScript are about as similar as cars and carpets. Also note that one is a compiler, and the other is a medium for execution.

Comment: Yes i knew that. What i wanted to ask was: are those language parsed and then interpreted by the VM or does V8 engine compile the code to machine language directly?

Comment: V8 compiles Javascript to machine code.

Comment: The answer is not related to the question also meh to “cars and carpets”

Answer (score 1):

They're two very different technologies, for two different programming languages - a Java Virtual Machine is a virtual machine for running Java programs, whereas V8 is a JavaScript engine. The fact that they have the word "Java" in the name is where the similarities end.

Comment: He asked if it works in a similar way, not if they implement the same language. He even mentioned specifically in his question that he knows that V8 is for "Javascript" and not Java.

Answer (score 0):

Google's V8 has nothing to do with Java. It's a JavaScript engine written in C++. You can read more about it [here](http://code.google.com/apis/v8/intro.html).

Comment: He didn't ask if it has anything to do with Java, he asked if it works in a SIMILAR way. Which it does (JIT et al).

Comment: @foljs - You are wrong: OP did ask if it has anything to do with Java. After I posted my answer, the question was edited in a way that completely changed it. The original version of the question (you can see the edit history by clicking on the date next to the "edited" note below the question) was titled "Is V 8 different from a Java Virtual Machine?" and asked: "If they don't work in the same manner, which are the differences?" That's the question I was answering.